# extracting some strings between two strings in a variable of a data frame in Python

Tags: python, string, extract

I am new in Python, dont have much knowledge, need a help on a problem i am having now
i have dataframe which has a variable say 'item' which is in text format, i need to pull the text between two strings say 'notify' and 'accordingly', i tried the below method but getting a blank output

```
start = 'to notify'
end = 'accordingly'
data_1['match'] = data_1['Issue'].apply(lambda x: "".join(x for x in x.split() if re.search(('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end)),x)))
```

I also tried re.findall but it is asking string or byte like objects, i tried to covert the variable from object to string, but it is not happening even. It will be really helpful if someone can help me on these problems...

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. _i tried to covert the variable from object to string, but it is not happening even._ Read the Pandas docs on working with text data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of a problem reading your code, but this snippet should do what I understand (get the text between a start and an end strings)

```
import pandas as pd
import re

start = 'to notify'
end = 'accordingly'

# I created an auxiliary function to better handle the errors
# when the patern start - text - end is not found
def extract_between(x, start, end):
    try:
        return re.match(pattern=r'.*{}(.*){}.*'.format(start, end), string=x).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        return None

# This is just an example, if it does not work for your porpoise please share some data
df = pd.DataFrame([('to notify TEXT accordingly'), ('this should not match')], columns=['issue'])
df['issue'] = df['issue'].apply(extract_between, **{'start': start, 'end': end})

print(df['issue'])
```

Comment: Hi Jano, this works, thanks for your help dear... :)